# How to prevent the push method from overwriting my items in an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm studying Typescript and VueJS, and I need to push my array, but it ends up overriding my 'name' property.
This is my code:

```
const itemsSelectedOptions = ref([])    
const nameTemplate = ref('')

function setItem(){
    //@ts-ignore
    itemsSelectedOptions.value.push({name: nameTemplate, fields: [...activities.value.selectedFields]})
}

 <template>
   <div>
     <input v-model="nameTemplate" />
     <button @click="setItem">Save Template</button>
   <div>
 </template>
```

Everything goes fine on my "fields" property, it doesn't overwrite. But in name always prevails the last value typed in "nameTemplate".
Anyway, I'll explain what "selectedFields" would be, they are boxes marked through a select.

Comment: hmm, i think it is because nameTemplate here uses a ref which is mutable object. have you tried using cloneDeep from lodash so something like this:
`itemsSelectedOptions.value.push({name: cloneDeep(nameTemplate), fields: [...]})`

I might be wrong though but just a suggestion (i dont really use vuejs much)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, push overwrites the array, use it instead "concat"

Also, I think this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) will be helpful.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying.
I tested it again using the concat method, but it didn't overwrite or add the item to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Vue has issues with push/concats sometimes. I generally overwrite with destructuring.

```
itemsSelectedOptions.value = [
    ...itemsSelectedOptions.value,
    {name: nameTemplate, fields: [...activities.value.selectedFields]}
]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! I tried this way but it kept overwriting. The weird part is that it worked when I put name like this: {name: {...nameTemplate}, fields: [...activities.value.selectedFields]}
But it still generated a problem in my select that uses "itemsSelectedOptions" as :options.

Comment: What kind of issues? push specifically supports reactivity, so generally it doesn't make sense to replace it